# How to write php code that uploads and immediately downloads that same file?

Tags: php, html

I'm currently working on my php hw, and I would appreciate any help. The hw is pretty simple. I create 1 php file that has a web form where you can upload a file and once you click submit, that same file is immediately downloaded to your hard drive. I copied and pasted what I have so far below. I think I'm confused because my professor mentioned using headers and readfile() to download a file but I don't know how I'm supposed to use a header inside a php file if it already has html elements that come before it, and I'm not allowed to create a separate php file.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> blah blah </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1> blah blah blah </h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input type ="file" accept = ".txt" name=fileUserSelected> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <?php
        $fileName = $_FILES['fileUserSelected']['name'];
        $currentLocation = $_FILES['fileUserSelected']['tmp_name'];
        $desiredLocation = __DIR__ . '/uploads/' . $fileName;
        move_uploaded_file($currentLocation, $desiredLocation);
      ?>
      <?php
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.txt"');
        readfile($_FILES['fileUserSelected']['name']);
      ?>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <hr>
      <small>
        &copy; blah blah  
      </small>
    </footer>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your code should be like this:
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type ="file" accept = ".txt" name=fileUserSelected> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="save-file" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save-file'])):
    $fileName = $_FILES['fileUserSelected']['name'];
    $currentLocation = $_FILES['fileUserSelected']['tmp_name'];
    $desiredLocation = __DIR__ . '/uploads/' . $fileName;
    move_uploaded_file($currentLocation, $desiredLocation);
    if(file_exists($desiredLocation):
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($desiredLocation).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($desiredLocation));
            flush(); // Flush system output buffer
            readfile($desiredLocation);
            die();
    else:
        die();
    endif;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn’t going to work as originally written because you’ll get a “headers already sent” error.  To avoid this error, follow this rule: php first, html last. This saves much heartache and as a bonus, makes code easier to read and refactor. It also lets you plug in concepts like the PRG pattern